# How to reformat a partition properly ?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, format, jfs

I want to create a case-insensitive partition (not loop-mounted). 
To this avail, I created a Ubuntu 16.04 VM in VirtualBox, and I manually partitioned the disk on startup (of Ubuntu-Install), into a 15 GB root partition, 4 GB Swap-Partition and 6 GB JFS partition.

This looks like that

[image: Initial Config]

It all works fine, I installed Ubuntu and everything works fine, even after reboot.

Unfortunately, I can't specify -O (case-insensitive) when I create the JFS partition during partition setup.

So after everything is installed, and the operating system is rebooted (successfully), I unmount the partition

```
umount /web
```

And recreate it with the -O option (=OS2-compatiblity = case-insensitive)

```
mkfs.jfs -O /dev/hda5
```

It says: this will delete all content, I choose [YES].

then I re-mount that filesystem:

```
mount /dev/hda5 /web
```

After /web is mounted, I create a file/folder called "Test" into /web, and then I try to create another file/folder called "test" in /web, and then it says: error, file already exists.
Superb, works as it should - file-system is case-insensitive.

[image: test]

But when I restart, I get

> Welcome to emergency boot mode...

and then, you basically can't do anything except deleting the VM, and re-importing the backup copy.

Why do I get emergency-boot-mode ? 
The root file-system at / which contains all the boot-stuff should not even be affected by any of the changes I made...
What am I missing ? 
How to get this to work ? 
[image: error 1]
[image: error 2]
[image: error 3]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is /web partiton automatically mounted?
when you remake the partition it changes the uuid
you have to update /etc/fstab with the new uuid.

EDIT: yes I see the lines, the system is crashing because it can't find /web by uuid. and since it is in fstab it is considered a dependant mount.

Comment: Ah, crap, that was indeed all. Thanks. Works fine now that I updated the uuid.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I recommend it wholeheartedly, but you can also run [**jsf_tune**](https://jfs.sourceforge.net/project/pub/jfs_tune.html#lbAE) to reuse the UUID of the old filesystem. [jsf_tune](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=lunar&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=jfs_tune) is provided by **jfsutils** (`sudo apt install jfsutils`) in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

```shellsession
# blkid /dev/hda5
/dev/hda5: UUID="e034928e-a30c-4d0e-82e4-2970204d6b1f" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="jfs"
# mkfs.jfs -O /dev/hda5
…
# jfs_tune -U "e034928e-a30c-4d0e-82e4-2970204d6b1f" /dev/hda5
jfs_tune version 1.1.15, 04-Mar-2011
UUID updated successfully.
```

Now you don't have to update `/etc/fstab`.